# How to find Number of Object in IBM i (AS400) Library and Use the object name in QTP

Tags: ibm-midrange, qtp, hp-uft

I want to automate my testing for Base update. Below is the scenario.  Please HELP!!!!!!

We are using IBM i (AS400) where we have n number of libraries. Suppose there is one library named Library1. In that library there are total of N objects/files so I want to get the count of all the objects in that library.

EG: Library1 contain 5 objects/files.

```
AA1
BB1
CC1
CC2
CC3
```

So What i want here is count of objects starting with the letter C.

Also, after getting the count of the number of objects, I need to search for a specific object in that library.

For that first I need to get the total count and then search. I have the logic with me but don't know how to code this in QTP.

QTP should get the count of the object.

Thanks
Moshin

Comment: Do you need to count ALL objects in Library1 or just files?  If just files, do you only need database files or printer and display files too?

Comment: What is `QTP`? (HP QTP?) What do you actually want to do? You seem to have two almost unrelated questions: "count objects" and "use object name in QTP".

Comment: To be more clear let me explain what I want.

I want to use QTP to get the list of all the files which are present in the library Library1 in my case all the 5 files. From that 5 file I want the file which start with C and form a list of those file.

Comment: Lets take an example of of Excel there are 2 column A & B. A column has 10 record A1-A10 and B column as 5 records B1-B5. Suppose the 5 records in B column are present in A column to get the records which are present in both the column we need to get the total count of both the column and then compare. Same logic i need implement in QTP. I need to get the total number of files in the library Library1 then out of those total number how many match with my criteria and get them in a list or arrary so that i can use them one by one in my QTP script for some validation which i need to perform

Answer (score 2):

If they are tables/views (aka PF & LF files), as opposed to other objects...

You can use an SQL statement over the SYSTABLES view

```
select count(*) 
from systables 
where sys_dname = 'LIBRARY1'
  and sys_tname like 'C%'
```

There are various other DB2 for i Catalog views that you might find helpful...
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm

Comment: IIRC, QTP allows you to run SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `DSPOBJD` command to an outfile...

```
DSPOBJD OBJ(LIBRARY1/*ALL) OBJTYPE(*ALL) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/QADSPOBJ)
```

The outfile will be based on `QADSPOBJ`.

Comment: I don't know what QTP is specifically ... but the outfile is just a file.  It can be queried using SQL or read directly using a HLL program, like any other.